# spring-xd work with xml payload

Tags: xml, spring, xpath, spring-integration, spring-xd

Is it possible to work with XML payload within the spring-XD runtime? I have the following which I am trying to execute stream:

```
stream create --name testingXML --definition "file --dir=/tmp/sample.xml 
              --outputType=application/xml | splitter --expression=//item | log"
```

My goal is to split upon a given XPATH expression (supported by Spring Integration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a "simple" splitter (rather than an XPath Splitter - XD currently doesn't have an XPathSplitter module), you need to use the [#xpath function](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xml.html#xpath-spel-function) in the expression.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!!! For completeness let me add the following points. 1: I had to add spring-integration-xml and spring-xml jars to classpath, and here is the the command that worked: `stream create --name testingXML2 --definition "file --dir=/opt/tuto/xd/ --outputType=text/plain | splitter --expression=\"#xpath(payload, '//item','document_list')\" | log" --deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Also XD does not currently support --outputType=application/xml . This means no automatic conversion of payloads to XML via JAXB, etc. But you don't need it if your producing module emits XML already.